# BASH - input redirection on command that has two arguments

Tags: bash, input, io-redirection

I am an undergrad CS student.

I just started on bash and I have a question.

How do I redirect input from a file to a command that requires two arguments like 'cmp', 'diff', 'grep'?

Is it possible that I have a txt file with 
"a1 a2"
and redirect this file to the input of cmp?

Thank you,

Comment: From *man 1 cmp* `cmp [OPTION]... FILE1 [FILE2 [SKIP1 [SKIP2]]]`

Comment: Also see the `<(...)` notation to treat an output stream like a file, as in `cmp <(process that makes input) <(process that makes other input)`

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. You can split the redirected input of a command into multiple arguments with `xargs`, for example:

```
echo pattern file | xargs grep
```

will execute `grep pattern file`. The input redirection can also come from a file, like this:

```
xargs grep < inputfile
```

`xargs` can do a lot more, basically it will take the standard input, split it into multiple arguments, and feed them to the given command.